# Where would this question go? "Best place to learn this or that"

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am simply going to write my question here. I have a feeling it would be rejected on StackOverflow.

To learn iOS development, there is that great free Stanford iTunes-U course. I am looking for something similar for Android development.

Answer (score 6):

Requests for external resources are specifically off-topic for any Stack Exchange site, including Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow is simply not the place for such questions; Stack Overflow maintains such a high quality *because* it focuses on objectively answerable questions.

You can ask such questions on [Slant](http://slant.co) instead; they are specifically set up for such subjective 'best place' questions.

Comment: I'm going to look into Slant - sounds good